# Apache Flink: Best way to architect many-to-one join on dynamic table?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, stream-processing, flink-sql

I have a resource with frequently added/updated rows called Orders, and a resource called UserProfile with less frequent (but often important) updates. I want to perform a continuous join query on these two resources (currently stored logically as dynamic tables in Flink) such that when a UserProfile update occurs, the join table emits a DataStream with **one updated EnrichedOrder per Order associated with that UserProfile**. The objective is to index this enriched denormalized data for efficient querying in a downstream data sink.

My question is, what is the best way to architect this join? Specifically, how do I ensure that *all* Order records on the "many" side of the join are enriched when a UserProfile is updated, while still keeping things performant?

Since an arbitrary inner join with no time window is not possible in Flink (presumably for performance reasons), I imagine setting an excessively large time window is discouraged as well.

What are the recommended approach(es) for this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flink 1.4.0, SQL does not support inner joins on streams without time boundaries and the DataStream API does not provide a nice syntax. However, it is possible to [hand-craft such a join](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html#low-level-joins) using a `CoProcessFunction`.

Flink 1.5.0 will support unbounded stream joins in SQL. By default, both input tables will be held completely in state. However, it is possible to configure a state retention time after which the state for inactive keys (inactive = not updated within the configured interval) is cleared.

Since the SQL support is implemented on top of the DataStream API, you could check the [implementation of the unbounded SQL join](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/49c6d10f186fb722d2a4003ce4d2219c01f55871/flink-libraries/flink-table/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/table/runtime/join/NonWindowInnerJoin.scala).

Comment: Didn't realize that feature was coming so soon, thanks so much for the info